# Why would I use an ordered hash in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm reading a tutorial and learned that PowerShell supports ordered hashes. When would I use that feature?

Sample code of what I'm talking about:

```
$hash = [ordered]@{ ID = 1; Shape = "Square"; Color = "Blue"}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me complement [Maximilian Burszley's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875534/45375) with a broader perspective:

**tl;dr**

- ***Most of the time* you want `[ordered] @{ ... }`** ([`[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary)) (PSv3+):

  - It provides enumeration of the entries *in the order in which they were defined* (also reflected in the `.Keys` and `.Values` collection properties).
  - It also allows accessing entries by *index*, like an array.
- Typically, you can use `[ordered] @{ ... }` interchangeably with `@{ ... }`, the regular hashtable, `[hashtable]` a.k.a [`[System.Collections.Hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable), because both types implement the [`[IDictionary]` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2), which is how parameters that accept hash tables are typically typed.

The performance penalty you pay for using `[ordered]` is negligible.

---

Some background:

**For *technical* reasons, the *most efficient* implementation of a hashtable (hash table)** is to **let the ordering of entries be the outcome of *implementation details*, *without guaranteeing any particular order* to the caller.**

This is fine for use cases where all you do is to perform isolated lookups by key, where the ordering among keys (entries) is irrelevant.

However, often you do care about the ordering of entries:

- in the simplest case, for *display* purposes; there is something disconcerting about seeing the definition order jumbled; e.g.:

  ```bash
    @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 } 

    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    one                            1
    three                          3   # !! 
    two                            2
  ```
- more importantly, the enumeration of entries may need to be predictable for further programmatic processing; e.g. (note: strictly speaking, property order doesn't matter in JSON, but it is again important for the human observer):

  ```bash
    # No guaranteed property order.
    PS> @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 } | ConvertTo-Json
    {
     "one": 1,
     "three": 3, # !!
     "two": 2
    }

    # Guaranteed property order.
    PS> [ordered] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 } | ConvertTo-Json
    {
      "one": 1,
      "two": 2,
      "three": 3
    }
  ```

**It's unfortunate that PowerShell's hashtable-literal syntax, `@{ ... }`, doesn't *default to* `[ordered]`<sup>[1]</sup>, but it is too late to change that.**

**There is one context in which `[ordered]` *is* implied**, however: if you cast a hashtable *literal* to `[pscustomobject]` in order to create a custom object:

**`[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is *syntactic sugar* for `[pscustomobject] [ordered] @{ ... }`**; that is, the resulting custom object's properties are ordered based on the entry order in the hashtable literal; e.g.:

```bash
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }

one two three  # order preserved!
--- --- -----
  1   2     3
```

Note, however, that this **only works exactly as shown above: if the cast applied *directly* to a hashtable *literal***; if you use a *variable* to store the hashtable in first or if you even just enclose the literal in `(...)` the ordering is lost:

```bash
PS> $ht = @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }; [pscustomobject] $ht

one three two  # !! Order not preserved.
--- ----- ---
  1     3   2


PS> [pscustomobject] (@{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }) # Note the (...)

one three two  # !! Order not preserved.
--- ----- ---
  1     3   2
```

Therefore, **if you construct a hashtable *iteratively* first and *then* cast it to `[pscustomobject]`, you must start with an `[ordered]` hashtable** to get predictable ordering of properties; this technique is useful, because it's easier to create hashtable entries than it is to add properties to a custom object; e.g.:

```bash
$oht = [ordered] @{} # Start with an empty *ordered* hashtable 
# Add entries iteratively.
$i = 0
foreach ($name in 'one', 'two', 'three') {
  $oht[$name] = ++$i
}
[pscustomobject] $oht # Convert the ordered hashtable to a custom object
```

Finally, note that `[ordered]` can only be applied to hashtable *literal*; you cannot use it to convert a preexisting regular hashtable to an ordered one (which wouldn't make any sense anyway, because you have no defined order to begin with):

```bash
PS> $ht = @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }; [ordered] $ht # !! Error
...
The ordered attribute can be specified only on a hash literal node.
...
```

On a side note: **Neither ordered nor regular hashtables enumerate their entries when sent through the pipeline**; they are sent as a whole.
To enumerate the entries, **use the `.GetEnumerator()` method**; e.g.:

```bash
@{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { $_.Value }
1
3  # !!
2
```

---

As for the **performance impact of using `[ordered]`**:

As noted, it is **negligible**; here are some sample timings, averaged across 10,000 runs, using [`Time-Command`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27):

```bash
Time-Command -Count 10000 { $ht=@{one=1;two=2;three=3;four=4;five=5;six=6;seven=7;eight=8;nine=9}; foreach($k in $ht.Keys){$ht.$k} }, 
                           { $ht=[ordered] @{one=1;two=2;three=3;four=4;five=5;six=6;seven=7;eight=8;nine=9}; foreach($k in $ht.Keys){$ht.$k} }
```

Sample timings (Windows PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10, single-core VM):

```bash
Command                 TimeSpan         Factor
-------                 --------         ------
$ht=@{one=1;two=2;th... 00:00:00.0000501 1.00  
$ht=[ordered] @{one=... 00:00:00.0000527 1.05
```

That is, `[ordered]` amounted to a mere 5% slowdown.

---

[1] Maximilian Burszley points out one **tricky aspect specific to `[ordered]` hashtables**:

With ***numeric* keys**, distinguishing between a *key* and an *index* can become tricky; **to force interpretation of a number as a *key*, cast it to `[object]` or use *dot notation* (`.`, property-access syntax) instead of *index syntax* (`[...]`)**:

```bash
# Ordered hashtable with numeric keys.
PS> $oht = [ordered] @{ 1 = 'one'; 2 = 'two' }

PS> $oht[1]  # interpreted as *index* -> 2nd entry
two

PS> $oht[[object] 1] # interpreted as *key* -> 1st entry.
one

PS> $oht.1 # dot notation - interpreted as *key* -> 1st entry.
one
```

That said, numeric keys aren't common, and to me the benefit of defaulting to predictable enumeration outweighs this minor problem.

The .NET type underlying `[ordered]`,  [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary), has been available since v1, so PowerShell could have chosen it as the default implementation for `@{ ... }` from the get-go, even in PowerShell v1.

Given PowerShell's commitment to backward compatibility, changing the default is no longer an option, however, as that could break existing code, namely in the following ways:

- There may be existing code that checks untyped arguments for whether they're a hashtable with `-is [hashtable]`, which would no longer work with an ordered hashtable (however, checking with `-is [System.Collections.IDictionary]` *would* work).
- There may be existing code that relies on hashtables with numeric keys, in which case the index-syntax lookup behavior would change (see example above).

Comment: *"doesn't default to ordered, but it is too late to change that."*, why? That is, what would break if it was changed that way (in some major version bump, probably)?

Comment: @hyde: While _some_ things have been broken, especially with the move to PowerShell _Core_, at this point the overall commitment, unfortunately, is still "backward compatibility forever". What could break? Code that uses reflection to look at the type passed; code that uses hashtables with numeric keys that would suddenly perform indexed access, to name two examples.

Comment: You've covered some in comments, but "_It's unfortunate that PowerShell's hashtable-literal syntax, @{ ... }, doesn't default to [ordered], but it is too late to change that... Given PowerShell's commitment to backward compatibility, changing the default is no longer an option, however, as that could break existing code._" **Not sure how going from "no guaranteed order" to "no guaranteed order, but it's always sorted" prevents a change.** You don't have to return different on reflection -- tougher to implement, but not breaking. I'm not sure about the second (indexed access); can you explain?

Comment: @ruffin, please see my update. In short: It isn't the ordering (not: sorting) that's the backward-compatibility concern, it is the behavioral change with numeric key lookups and expecting hashtable literals to be of type `[hashtable]` (I'm not sure if that's what you were suggesting, but fudging the reflection behavior results sounds ill-advised to me).

Comment: @mklement0 "_I'm not sure if [fudging the reflection behavior results is] what you were suggesting_". So, um... yes, that's it exactly, and [crazier things have been done](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2281932), but that's probably also the part of me that enjoys a good excuse to monkeypatch, so let's not listen to him. I see your point. ;^) Thank you for the changes.

Answer (score 10):

The reason for an `ordered` dictionary is for display / typecast purposes.  For example, if you want to cast your `hashtable` to a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) and you want your keys to be in the order you enter them, you use `ordered`.

The use case here is when you use [`Export-Csv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Export-Csv), the headers are in the right order. This is just one example I could think of off the top of my head. By design, the `hashtable` type doesn't care about the order you enter keys/values and will be different each time you display it to the success stream.

An additional use-case for the `ordered` dictionary: you can treat your hashtable as an array and use numerical accessors to find items, such as `$myOrderedHash[-1]` will grab the last item added to the dictionary.

Comment: Actually, due to built-in syntactic sugar, you do _not_ need `[ordered]` when casting a hashtable to a `[pscustomobject]`.

Comment: @mklement0 Sometimes I use a hashtable to build an object throughout a function (`$hashtable[$dynamic] = $value`) and cast it at the end `return [pscustomobject]$hashtable`

Comment: Yes, but it's worth pointing out that you only need `[ordered]` it if you create the (ordered) hashtable _first_, and _then_ cast from a _variable_  (or expression). There are too many examples of unnecessary `[pscustomobject] [ordered] @{ ... }` out there.

Comment: @mklement0 I hear you now.  No, I do not perform that action 